# Dijkstra's: Where is the equation from? m < n^2/log n

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, graph-theory, dijkstra

In this passage from my textbook:

> [image: screenshot from a textbook, with some inequalities highlighted with red rectangles]

where are the inequalities from? (The ones that I've marked with red rectangles.) I feel that they describe a relationship between vertices and edges in a graph, but I don't understand it.

Comment: Can you post the actual text, rather than a screenshot? (Screenshots aren't usable for people using assistive technologies, they aren't findable via Google, etc.)

Comment: Is this on-topic for Stack Overflow? You might find better answers at [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: They come from earlier in the same paragraph. If m < n^2 / log n, then O(m log n) < O(n^2), otherwise the reverse.

Comment: @hobbs, you are right! thank you very much! Now I get it!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this not a programming question; it fits better on cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

You have two implementations of Dijkstra’s algorithm to choose from. One runs in time O((m + n) log n) = O(m log n), assuming the graph is connected. The other runs in time O(n<sup>2</sup>). The question is where the crossover point is between these two runtimes. Equating and simplifying gives that

> m log n = n<sup>2</sup>
>
> m = n<sup>2</sup> / log n

So if m is asymptotically smaller than n<sup>2</sup> / log n, you’d prefer the heap implementation, and if m is asymptotically bigger than n<sup>2</sup> / log n you’d prefer the unsorted sequence approach.

(Note that, with a Fibonacci heap, the runtime of Dijkstra’s algorithm is O(m + n log n), which is never asymptotically worse than O(n<sup>2</sup>).)